# Short-Circuiting in R element-wise & or | operators

Tags: r

I am trying to understand how short-circuiting is implemented in R. Here is an example data.frame:

```
 v <- data.frame(id=c(1,2,3,4), effective_from=c('', '1/1/2001', '10/1/2001', '1/1/2002'), effective_to=c('', '1/10/2001', '', '1/1/2001'))
  id effective_from effective_to
1  1                            
2  2       1/1/2001    1/10/2001
3  3      10/1/2001             
4  4       1/1/2002     1/1/2001
```

I would think the following statement would work (suppose `effective_from` and `effective_to` are strings which could contain a Date or be blank).

```
str_length(v$effective_from) > 0 & str_length(v$effective_to) > 0 & as.Date(v$effective_from) > as.Date(v$effective_to)
```

But I get an error saying:

> ```
> Error in charToDate(x) : 
>   character string is not in a standard unambiguous format
> ```

I was expecting to get: `FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE` after running my statement above instead of the error.

I would have thought if the length of either `effective_from` or `effective_to` is < 1 then it won't perform the subsequent steps. I would imagine in the first row that since `effective_from` is blank my statement above would return FALSE when trying to evaluate `str_length('effective_from')` thus short-circuiting further evaluation.

Not sure why it isn't working... How would I implement a short-circuiting element-wise AND or OR?

Comment: May be the `Date` format is not the correct default format i.e. may be you need `format = yourformat`  `(as.Date(v$effective_from) > as.Date(v$effective_to))`

Comment: Are you passing a string as `""` or `NULL`

Comment: Use `&&`, not `&` for short circuit evaluation.

Comment: In that case `any(nchar(v$effective_from) ==0)` before the `<`

Comment: R operates on whole vectors.  You can't short-circuit some elements and not others.

Comment: It may be also better to create an index and skip  those elements

Comment: Try `i1 <- with(v, nchar(effective_from)  > 0  &nchar(effective_to) > 0); with(v, length(effective_from[i1]) > 0 & length(effective_to[i1])  >0 & as.Date(effective_from[i1]) > as.Date(effective_to[i1]))`

Comment: Or a better approach would be to change thew `""`  to `NA` which wouldn't throw error `v1 <- c("2012-05-06", ""); as.Date(replace(v1, v1 == "", NA))
[1] "2012-05-06" NA`

Comment: Updated question...

Comment: @Denis In your example, what is the format `m/d/y` or `d/m/y`

Comment: Date Format is m/d/y

Comment: @Denis I already mentioned about the `format` in my first comment

Comment: @akrun, it didn't occur to me that it was required but yes, you were first to the punch. It's usually optional...

Comment: Your answer wasn't bad. You should keep it. I did end up using NA afterwards as it is easier than dealing with counting characters. That was a good idea!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a base R solution, where `nchar()` + `as.vector()` + `as.Date()` are used:

```
res <- with(v, nchar(as.vector(effective_from)) >0 
            & nchar(as.vector(effective_to))>0
            & as.Date(as.vector(effective_from), "%m/%d/%Y") > as.Date(as.vector(effective_to), "%m/%d/%Y"))
```

such that

```
> res
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

Comment: ah, so all I was missing was the `format`? Oh, duh!

Comment: @Denis I guess so. and also your columns are factors, so you need them as vectors in your code

Comment: `str_length(x)` does `as.character(x)`

Comment: @Denis, great, then you don't need `as.vector()`